# How to install newer version of package in conda in case of conflicts?

Tags: python, installation, conda

At the moment I have torch of version `1.8.0` installed in my conda enviroment:

```
pytorch                   1.8.0           cpu_py39hc766e51_1    conda-forge
```

The latest stable version is `1.10.0` and it is listed in the output of `conda search`:

```
pytorch                       1.10.0 cpu_py39h7601aee_0  conda-forge
```

However, when attempting to install newer version by `conda install pytorch=1.10` I receive the message of package conflicts:

```
Package sleef conflicts for:
torchvision -> pytorch -> sleef[version='>=3.5.1,<4.0a0']
pytorch=1.10.0 -> sleef[version='>=3.5.1,<4.0a0']
torchmetrics -> pytorch[version='>=1.3'] -> sleef[version='>=3.5.1,<4.0a0']
pytorch-lightning -> pytorch[version='>=1.6'] -> sleef[version='>=3.5.1,<4.0a0']
```

And a lot stuff of this kind.

How can resolve this issue and update the pytorch version in the enviroment? Or the only option would be to create new enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update relevant dependent packages as well [link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#listing-package-dependencies)

other option would be to update all the packages in your conda environment using

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: `conda update --all` has updated some of the packages, but excluding `pytorch`. If I try to update it directly `conda update pytorch` I receive a message, that it is already `up-to-date`. Seems like newer version of `pytorch` is a separate unconnected entity.

Comment: I'm not facing the issue on macOS, this PyTorch problem seems to have been occurring for many seems. found "conda update pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit -c pytorch" on pytorch forum, may be you can give it a try?

Comment: @S N unfortunately, it didn't work. Actually, I am on Mac with M1 - can it be due to the issues with this. Probably, there is no support for arm